# Liferay - Link in Dockbar depedent on user group using hook

Tags: hook, liferay

I am fairly new to the new liferay platform and using hooks. I am adding the currently logged-in user's email next to their name in the `Dockbar portlet`. I would like this email to link to, when clicked, to a different link depending on whether the user is in either of two groups.

This is what I have written so far in the hook...

```
//if user is in "group1" show this link

<aui:a cssClass='<%= "user-email"  %>' href="link1" title="Gmail">
    <%= "(" + HtmlUtil.escape(user.getDisplayEmailAddress() + ")") %>
</aui:a>

//if user is in "group2" show this link

<aui:a cssClass='<%= "user-email"  %>' href="link2" title="Outlook">
    <%= "(" + HtmlUtil.escape(user.getDisplayEmailAddress() + ")") %>
</aui:a>
```

How can I achieve this should I be using a `<c:if>` tag? or can someone exemplify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve the `scopeGroupId` available in the dockbar's jsp and from that you can retrieve the `Group` instance.

And then check on which group's page the User is currently and change the `href` accordingly.

or you can also use the following code in your JSP:

```
Group group = null;
if(themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroup().isSite()) { // this will tell if the Group is a site or not
    group = themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroup(); // fetching the site group instance
}

String href;
if (themeDisplay.getLayout().getGroup().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("group1")) {
    href = "group1_link";
} else {
    href = "group2_link";
}
```

Note: `themeDisplay` is available in Liferay's JSP and to use in your custom portlets you can use `<liferay-theme:defineObjects />` tag.

Hope I have understood your question properly and answered accordingly.